# JSOUP not working as expected

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I used JSOUP to get some text from urls in my app. Its working fine most of the times but some time its not working. Like if I exit the app and reopen it then it works, sometime not.

```
  try {
                Document document = Jsoup
                        .connect(url)
                        .userAgent(
                                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                        .get();
                Elements myin = null;
                myin = document.select("div.fontdef1");
                desc = myin.text().toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The url I used is like  `url=http://www..abc.com/"+data+"/` ,`String data` changes for each case.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Wrong url. Add http:// in front.

Comment: I used http://. The above is an example not the one I used.

Comment: When you say, it doesn't work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: No error. I set output string into textview,that's not working sometime(String is null), and when I reopen the app it works just like that.

Comment: Do you see this behavior for the same `data` string in the url?